# How to index headlines and text on reactive website

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuejs3

I use vue js + router (with web history) and I am not sure how can I sendto google information about dynamic content like headlines etc.

I can see google indexed meta data, he can see different URL's but he is not able process any headline or other part of content.

I can't use server side rendering and I need that seamles js reactivity between pages for some project specific reasons.

is there any kind of API or approach how can I tell google what headlines and content is on those dynamic pages?

Comment: have you try `vue-meta` https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/

Comment: I have modul for meta data and I can see google is able index them. I can search website by them. But the headlines and content is different.